# What is this plastic edging around my window called?

Tags: windows, timber-framing

I have a timber  frame house  that has done a bit of settling and im fairly confident its now done after 3 years, so time to fix the various cracks.
Around one of the windows there is this plastic beading that has popped out. I need to fix it.

Can anyone advise what this is called?

[image: Beading that has popped out]

Comment: It looks like J channel but it is difficult to tell for sure. I am not sure why it would have been used in that application.

Comment: its used around all the windows so the windows dont directly meet with the render, to give a nicer finish. im fairly sure its more aesthetic than anything else

Comment: I understand why something was put there i was just saying that J-channel, if it is J-channel,  would be a surprising  choice to me for that application. You could try to carefully get it out, clean it up and trim to length if necessary and caulk it back in place.

Comment: I think you are correct Alaska man you should make that an answer. Possibly a close up photo might change our opinion but trimming and stuffing back in with a sealer should work.